# problems with anaconda. when i uninstall anaconda, there is an error warning. Not knowing why

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

One problem. When I click Uninstall-Anaconda.exe to uninstall anaconda, I got a response (Installation error : Traceback (most recent call last): .....) during the uninstalling. However when I click OK, I can still uninstall it. But I don't know whether this error will have any influence or not.

[image]

Also, when i finished installing anaconda. there are 2 prompt: "anaconda prompt" and "anaconda powershell prompt". When I run "anaconda prompt", it directly open a terminal and show: "[process exited with code 1 (0x00000001)]". But when i click "anaconda powershell prompt", everything is normal. Is there any one knows why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the previous installation of the Anaconda (or Miniconda, ...). During the first installation, an `AutoRun` key is added to the `"HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"` in the Windows Registry. When you uninstall the Anaconda, this `AutoRun` key remains intact and interferes with the next installation of Anaconda (or Miniconda). The solution is simple, just remove the key from the registry after uninstallation of Anaconda:

```
C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /f
```